# Como organizar itens do listbox html?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho 2 listbox onde passo os itens de um para outro, mas ele sempre adiciona no fim da lista, gostaria de conseguir organizar a lista a meu gosto, estilo ItemUP, ItemDown na segunda lista, veja que não é ordenar, mas organizar na sequencia que quero.

O codigo para

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btnA').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#listaA option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nenhum item selecionado");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#listaB').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#btnB').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#listaB option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nenhum item selecionado");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#listaA').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select multiple id="listaA">
        <option value="1">Item1</option>
        <option value="2">Item2</option>
        <option value="3">Item3</option>
        <option value="4">Item4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="btnA" value="> > >">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="btnB" value="< < <">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select multiple id="listaB">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Procurei na web mas só encontrei Sort, que ordena  lista, mas não é isso que quero, quero organizar manualmente.

Comment: Você queria organizar manualmente.. você diz arrastar o itemx pra cima do itemy e etc?

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas já encontrei a solução neste site: [link] http://viralpatel.net/blogs/listbox-select-all-move-left-right-up-down-javascript/